# Students who are passed in all subjects and having total marks greater than 170

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by, aggregate-functions

SQL> select * from marks;

```
 STUDENTID  SUBJECTID    MARK
---------- ---------- ----------
     1          1         **21**
     1          2         75
     1          3         87
     2          1         82
     2          2         64
     2          3         77
     3          1         82
     3          2         **23**
     3          3         67
```

9 rows selected.

Need to calculate who are passed in all subjects(>30 in each subject) and having total mark >170
Here output like :

```
 STUDENTID  Status         Total_MARK

 ---------- ----------      ----------

  2           Passed              223
```

Comment: Please edit your question and show what you have tried.

Comment: I am a new user and this is my first question. Could you please suggest what do I need to edit ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use grouping with having clause as below

```
 select student_id, 'Passed' as status, sum(mark) as total_mark 
   from marks
  group by student_id
 having sum(mark)>170 and min(mark)>30;
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://rextester.com/YNBNU14494)</kbd>

**Edit** *( due to your last comment ) :* Using

```
with marks( student_id, mark ) as
(
 select 1, 21 from dual union all
 select 1, 75 from dual union all
 select 1, 87 from dual union all
 select 2, 82 from dual union all
 select 2, 64 from dual union all
 select 2, 77 from dual union all
 select 3, 82 from dual union all
 select 3, 23 from dual union all
 select 3, 67 from dual
)
 select student_id as "Student ID", 
        case when sum(mark)>170 and min(mark)>30 then 
                  sum(mark)||' (Passed)' 
        else
                  sum(mark)||' (Failed)'         
        end as "Total Mark (Status)"
   from marks
  group by student_id;

Student ID  Total Mark (Status)
----------  -------------------
1           183 (Failed)
2           223 (Passed)
3           172 (Failed)
```

might be a smart way by combining `Total Mark` and `Status`. If you really want to sperate those columns, then need to write seperate `case when` statemants as in the similar manner.

Comment: Way simpler than I thought. Sometimes my brain goes into "overthinking" mode. +1

Comment: :) yes, through the life all of us might meet such conditions, thank you @TheImpaler

Comment: Thanks @BarbarosÖzhan for your answer. If I need to add all the failed person details how can I do it ?                                                                    
 STUDENTID  Status         Total_MARK

 ----------            ----------      ----------
 1                     Failed                183      
  2                    Passed              223

Comment: Thanks a ton Barbaros Özhan. This is really a smart way to get the output.